Type not working as expected in React component
I've got a <Button /> component which can take several props fullWidth, iconName and iconPosition which as the name suggests would render an icon in the button. I made a base type which extends the native HTML button and added fullWidth: string. This type is then extended twice to cover the icon cases adding iconPosition: 'icon-left' | 'icon-right' | 'icon-only' and iconName: string, and when iconPosition = 'icon-only' I remove the children prop and then have the aria-label prop as required. I made a code sandbox which can be viewed here. The types then look like this:
type IconPosition = "icon-only" | "icon-right" | "icon-left";
type IconName = "avatar" | "circle" | "email";

// Attempt One
type BasePropsAttemptOne = {
  fullWidth?: boolean;
} & ComponentPropsWithRef<"button">;

type ButtonWithIconAttemptOne = {
  iconPosition: Exclude<IconPosition, "icon-only">;
  iconName: IconName;
} & BasePropsAttemptOne;

type ButtonWithIconOnlyAttemptOne = {
  iconPosition: Extract<IconPosition, "icon-only">;
  iconName: IconName;
  "aria-label": string;
} & Omit<BasePropsAttemptOne, "children">;

type PropsAttemptOne =
  | BasePropsAttemptOne
  | ButtonWithIconAttemptOne
  | ButtonWithIconOnlyAttemptOne;

// Attempt two
type BasePropsAttemptTwo = {
  fullWidth?: boolean;
} & ComponentPropsWithRef<"button">;

type ButtonWithIconAttemptTwo = {
  iconPosition: Exclude<IconPosition, "icon-only">;
  iconName: IconName;
};

type ButtonWithIconOnlyAttemptTwo = {
  iconPosition: Extract<IconPosition, "icon-only">;
  iconName: IconName;
  "aria-label": string;
  children?: never;
};

type ButtonNoIconAttemptTwo = {
  iconPosition?: never;
  iconName?: never;
};

type PropsAttemptTwo = BasePropsAttemptTwo &
  (
    | ButtonWithIconAttemptTwo
    | ButtonWithIconOnlyAttemptTwo
    | ButtonNoIconAttemptTwo
  );

The problem is my first attempt of just extending the base type didn't work as expected as I could satisfy the types by only passing iconPosition: 'icon-only' aria-label: 'something' which is wrong as it should also show me a type error that iconName is missing.
In my second attempt I don't extend the base type and instead use unions and intersections so that the type reads as "the props will be of base type and then could also be one of the icon types". This works better than attempt one but when it comes to passing children to a button with icon-only instead of the type error saying "children does not exist on type.." it says "Type '"icon-only"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'" which is not helpful.
Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do or am I missing something here?

You can use generics for conditional types, also notice how i removed children?: never and used Omit in conditional type instead, ButtonNoIconAttemptTwo can simply be an empty object type as it does not add any other properties.
type IconPosition = "icon-only" | "icon-right" | "icon-left";
type IconName = "avatar" | "circle" | "email";

type BasePropsAttemptTwo = {
  fullWidth?: boolean;
} & ComponentPropsWithRef<"button">;

type ButtonWithIconAttemptTwo = {
  iconPosition: Exclude<IconPosition, "icon-only">;
  iconName: IconName;
};

type ButtonWithIconOnlyAttemptTwo = {
  iconPosition: Extract<IconPosition, "icon-only">;
  iconName: IconName;
  "aria-label": string;
};

type ButtonNoIconAttemptTwo = {};

type PropsAttemptTwo<T extends (
    | ButtonWithIconAttemptTwo 
    | ButtonWithIconOnlyAttemptTwo
    | ButtonNoIconAttemptTwo
    )> = (T extends ButtonWithIconOnlyAttemptTwo ? Omit<BasePropsAttemptTwo, "children"> : BasePropsAttemptTwo) & T


